# Stange issues using MapKit in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I am experiencing some strange issues while trying to show a region in SwiftUI app with MapView.
I am using coordinates from external GPS - coordinates are correctly loaded (checked during debug)
I use the onReceive method to update the view, when my location changes (NMEA string updates every 1 second).
It is strange because I can see that view is moving but it is only grid, there is no picture of sea, land, whatever.
If I change the span to different values sometimes I get error that tiles can't be loaded and sometimes this warning is cleared.

Any ideas?

here is my code:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  ExtasyCompleteNavigation
//
//  Created by Vasil Borisov on 13.06.23.
//

import SwiftUI
import Network
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var navigationReadings = NavigationReadings.sharedInstance
    @StateObject var authorization = LocationModel.shared
    
    //used for testing data
    //@State var nextString = String()
    
    @State var coordinateregion = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: .init(latitude: 43.19, longitude: 27.89), latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            //you have to call it like that to mute the warning
            AreaMap(region: $coordinateregion)
//                .overlay(){
//                    Text("lat: \(navigationReadings.lat), lon: \(navigationReadings.lon)")
//                }
                .onReceive(navigationReadings.$location) { location in

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.coordinateregion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, latitudinalMeters: 10, longitudinalMeters: 10)
                    }
                }
            
            HStack(){
                CompassStaticView(heading: CGFloat(navigationReadings.courseOverGround))
                    .overlay(CompassView(heading: CGFloat(navigationReadings.courseOverGround)))
                AnemometerView(windAngle: navigationReadings.windAngle, windSpeed: navigationReadings.windSpeed)
            }//END OF HSTACK
            .padding()
            
            //                    Text("Received Data:")
            //                    TextEditor(text: $navigationReadings.receivedData)
            //                        .frame(minWidth: 300, minHeight: 200)
            //                        .padding()
            //                    Text("Error:")
            //                    TextEditor(text: $navigationReadings.error)
            Button("Start Listetnig"){
                //declared in locationmanager
                self.authorization.requestAuthorisation()
                navigationReadings.listenerStart()
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            Button("Stop Listening"){
                navigationReadings.udpSocket.close()
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }//END OF VSTACK
    }//END OF BODY
} //END OF CONTENT VIEW


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

//upodating the view from the main thread to silence warnings and
//prevent undefined behaviour
struct AreaMap: View {
    @Binding var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    
    var body: some View {
        let binding = Binding(
            get: { self.region },
            set: { newValue in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.region = newValue
                }
            }
        )
        return Map(coordinateRegion: binding)
            //.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of that custom binding in the body for region. The body of a View is synchronous there is no reason to make it asynchronous

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That was my original code but then SwiftUI complains with following warning:2023-09-08 18:22:26.801396-0600 **ExtasyCompleteNavigation[1435:17642] [SwiftUI] Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.** 
Even with that removed I still can't get the mapview to work. 
I just don't see how to display location with external coordinates... shall I create custom class and delegate / protocol similar to the CLLocation and its delegate method? 
Please share your thoughts